# Adding an API to IdentityServer4

Tags: .net, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an API and client that I created using the quickstart for Identity Server and it's working.  In the config file I have the API called api1 that I have set as the allowed scope for a user I created called Admin.  In turn this allows me to call the controller in the API project called IdentityController.  This returns some data about the claims.  Works great.  I added a new controller called MsgController with authorize, and it to can be called without a problem.  However I need some guidance on the following:

1. I want to give a new user the allowed scope of api2 and then only allow that scope to call MsgController
2. How do I prevent the allowed scope "api1" from being used in MsgController, and prevent "api2" (the new scope I want to create) from using the IdentityController.

Ideally I need to create a test with two logins and show that they cannot access the other controller based on their scope.  I thought that the name of the scope would correlate with the name of the controller, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I think this is my lack of understanding on how to apply scopes to api's.

Thanks.

Comment: Either you can enable role-based access (this uses claims) or implement action filters (here we can use custom logic along with claims)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to restrict the controllers using policies.

in your startup.cs `ConfigureService()` add the following extension

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    //policy1
    options.AddPolicy("api1Policy", builder =>
    {
        builder.RequireClaim("scope", "api1");
    });

    //policy2
    options.AddPolicy("api2Policy", builder =>
    {
        builder.RequireClaim("scope", "api2");
    });
});
```

For more complex policy validations you can use, `builder.RequireAssertion();`

In your controllers add the annotation like this.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "api2Policy")]
public class MsgController: Controller
{
   //Users with api2 scope will be allowed in here. Likewise, do the same for others.
}
```

For more details about refer, [Reference1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1) [Reference2](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/topics/apis.html)

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I was looking for.